# automating FTP session

Tags: perl, bash, ftp, ksh

I have the following excerpt from a perl script to automate an FTP session, I'm hoping someone can explain how it works.

```
system("rsh some_server ftp -in ftp.something.com << !
user anonymous someone\@somewhere.org
some ftp commands
bye");
```

The background. This perl script runs on a Linux machine, it remotes into a Solaris machine. The FTP session must be executed from the Solaris machine because the FTP site performs IP address checking.

Formerly this script ran on the Solaris machine directly (i.e. it didn't use rsh) I hacked it around and came up with this which seems to work. However I have little idea how, in particular I don't understand the `<< !` bit at the end of the first line. It looks a little like a here-document but I'm not really sure.

Any explanations welcome.

Comment: it looks fragile and error prone, I would stick with Net::FTP and Net::SSH2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `<<` is a heredoc, which is made clear by the following warning (which I get when I take out the `rsh` command):

```
sh: line 2: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `!')
```

The construct

```
<< HEREDOC
```

reads as standard input everything from `HEREDOC` up to a line containing only `HEREDOC` *or up to an end-of-file character*. When you put this after a command, it is equivalent to

```
command < file
```

where `file` contains the text in the heredoc. In your case, instead of `HEREDOC` the delimiter is `!`, so the `!` is *not* passed to `ftp` but everything after `!` is. This is equivalent to

```
$ cat file
user anonymous someone\@somewhere.org
some ftp commands
bye
$ ftp -in ftp.something.com < file
```

`rsh` takes that entire command and runs it on your remote host.

As illustrated by user1146334's answer, this command does not act on the principal of least surprise. At the very least, make it less confusing by changing it to

```
system("rsh some_server ftp -in ftp.something.com << HEREDOC
user anonymous someone\@somewhere.org
some ftp commands
bye
HEREDOC");
```

Or even better, as mpapec mentioned in the comments, use [Net::FTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) and [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/Net-SSH2-0.52/lib/Net/SSH2.pm).

Comment: I like the idea of using 'HEREDOC' as the heredoc delimiter. Got to agree that this code is confusing. Clearly the original author was also confused. Using the appropriate perl modules would be better, but of course I'm working with existing code and it's not always practical to rewrite everything. At least that's what they tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the man page?

```
-i    Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.

-n    Restrains ftp from attempting “auto-login” upon initial connection.  If auto-login is enabled, ftp will check the .netrc (see netrc(5)) file in the user's
       home directory for an entry describing an account on the remote machine.  If no entry exists, ftp will prompt for the remote machine login name (default is
       the user identity on the local machine), and, if necessary, prompt for a password and an account with which to login.


 The client host and an optional port number with which ftp is to communicate may be specified on the command line.  If this is done, ftp will immediately attempt
 to establish a connection to an FTP server on that host; otherwise, ftp will enter its command interpreter and await instructions from the user.  When ftp is
 awaiting commands from the user the prompt ‘ftp>’ is provided to the user.  The following commands are recognized by ftp:

 ! [command [args]]
             Invoke an interactive shell on the local machine.  If there are arguments, the first is taken to be a command to execute directly, with the rest of
             the arguments as its arguments.
```

So essentially you're ftp'ing in and providing a new command per line in-line instead of from a file.

Comment: Yes I did look at the man page but I still don't understand. What does `<<` do? `!` shells out of an FTP session, so how does that help? What I would like is a step by step explanation of how the script works. Which parts are being iterpreted by what processes etc.